# Oracle APEX: Update a row when ID has the same value with a Form on a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

Im currently working with Oracle APEX and have some problems. 
I have an inventory table and a bike table. I want to assign a part to a bike. So I also have a bike_with_inventory table which contains the **ID of the bike**, **the ID of the inventory** and the **bike_with_inventory ID**. 
Now in APEX, I have a Form on the bike_with_inventory table where I select a bike and a part for the bike. I made a form on a table and its working. The only problem is that if the part already is in the bike it generates a new ID in the bike_with_inventory table instead of updating it. I tried to do it with a merge

```
MERGE INTO bike_with_inventory bwi
    USING (SELECT ID, targetAmount FROM bike_with_inventory) i
        ON (bwi.ID = i.ID)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET bwi.targetAmount =bwi.targetAmount + :P17_TARGET_AMOUNT;
```

But if I process this Merge it does what I want. But also generates a new ID. So it updates the selected one with e.g 5 and also generates an ID with targetAmount 5. 
Can someone help me with this ? I hope I could explain it, so that youre able to understand my problem. Thank you a lot. PS im using APEX 5.1. But I guess also non APEX can understand that i guess its not that hard of a problem.